# Rendering UIs / Generating GSPs directly from pencil or balsamiq wireframes

Tags: grails, user-interface, automation, gsp, wireframe

Are there any existing tools/combination-of-tools I can use so that my wireframes built using pencil or balsamiq can be directly used by my application (grails) for rendering the UI? Or maybe a way to generate GSP's out of my wireframes (assuming there is a set style guide etc.)? I am essentially looking to do away with having to code the HTML/GSP for each and every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Napkee](http://www.napkee.com/) is a commercial solution. I don't know any completely free one, though

Comment: Right now im looking for free options. May end up developing one.

Comment: Found [this blog post](http://development.nedeco.de/blog/2011/11/03/balsamiq-mockups-to-htmlcss-converter/) and [this project on github](https://github.com/cory/mockup) and [this project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/bmml2any/)

Comment: Super helpful links them. Thanx a ton.